# Error al hacer una migración mysql en Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy creando un proyecto en laravel 9 y cuando hago la migración a la base de datos me salta un error y no entiendo que pasa, acá dejo el error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: segun el error parece que tu entidad en laravel no concuerda con los dato o estrcutura de base de datos...

Comment: como tu pregunta casi no tiene informacion es poco lo que se puede hacer ...

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el esquema de la tabla `users` (con un `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`)? Todo apunta a que el tamaño del campo `users_email_unique` supera los 1000 octetos, lo que sobrepasa el tamaño máximo de las claves. Ten en cuenta que juegos de caracteres multiocteto, como UTF-8, no cuentan un carácter como un octeto, si no que reserva varios para el peor de los casos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial, Laravel usa el juego de caracteres utf8mb4 por defecto, que incluye soporte para almacenar "emojis" en la base de datos. Si está ejecutando una versión de MySQL anterior a la versión 5.7.7 o MariaDB anterior a la versión 10.2.2, es posible que deba configurar manualmente la longitud de cadena predeterminada llamando al método Schema::defaultStringLength dentro de su AppServiceProvider localizado en el directorio app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Link a la documentación mencionada: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-indexes